# Bitmap Size in C# and mono

Tags: c#, bitmap, mono, panel, scaling

I want to draw a diagram in a bitmap and then draw this bitmap to a panel (or Picturebox). This program should work in .NET as well as mono. But there is an issue with scaling.

For testing I did a simple WinForm program with a yellow panel (500x500 pixel). Then I draw a bitmap with the same size but different color into the panel:

```
private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // make a bitmap with size 500x500 pixel
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 500, 500);
        }

        //Draw the bitmap on the panel
        Graphics gpanel = e.Graphics;
        gpanel.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
    }
```

The issue is that I get three different results:
1. Windows .NET: works fine, the complete panel is filled with the red bitmap.
2. mono SuseLinux: the top is filled red, but at the bottom of the panel I can still see a part of the panel.
3. mono Rasperry: The bitmap is at the top left of the panel, and I can still see a part of the panel at the right and at the bottom.

Here are the results:
Windows .NET:
[image]

Mono Opensuse:
[image]

Mono Raspberry PI:
[image]

What can be done to get the same result on all machines. Is it possible that I found a bug in mono ? Or do I something wrong ?

Comment: It seems like the red color is always a square in every case. To me, the problem seems to be the size of the container the Mono Openhouse and Mono Raspberry have.

Comment: Yes, you should report to Mono as a bug.

Comment: Are each of 500x500 bitmaps the same size and the panel skewed in size, or is the panel fixed at 500x500 and the bitmap scaled smaller within the panel, NOT in code, but actual on screen size (i.e. screen cap and measured?)

Comment: the bitmap is really 500x500, it seems that the panel is larger as defined in the program